# Error 404 on SpringMVC using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I keep getting this Error 404 and I've done/looked at almost all the solutions on StackOverflow that are relevant and still haven't fixed my problem. Why am I having this error?

When I do http://localhost:8080 it gives me my index.jsp page, but when I do http://localhost:8080/index.jsp of http://localhost:8080/WebApp/index.jsp it gives me 404 error.

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven />

        <context:component-scan base-package="test.app" />
        <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>



</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

index.jsp

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: reaganyuan
  Date: 12/31/17
  Time: 12:42 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>$Title$</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>HELLO WORLD</p>
</body>
</html>
```

TestController.java

```html
package test.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String test()
    {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>



       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

</project>
```

My Project structure
[image: project structure]

edit: I changed `index()` into `test()` in the controller, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: The index.jsp is getting resolved by the view resolver. There is no mapping directly to index.jsp

Comment: In Web.xml try changing url-pattern to /*.html as shown below

Answer (score 0):

In Web.xml try changing url-pattern to /* as shown below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried this as well and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the url `http://localhost:8080/` you are hitting the TestController which has a mapping for "/". It is returning a string `"index"` which will be resolved by the `InternalResourceViewResolver.class` into index.jsp.

You do not have any mapping to /index.jsp. In a servlet container you can't access the files like that directly. If you still want you can change your controller like this.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/","index.jsp"})
    public String test()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But my advice is not to do like that. You should keep only the name without extension, like `@RequestMapping(value={"/","index"})`

Comment: what is the error you are getting? What is the url you are hitting?

Comment: localhost:8080 it gives me my index.jsp page, but when I do http://localhost:8080/index.jsp or http://localhost:8080/WebApp/index.jsp it gives me 404 error.

Comment: can you send me your project to rajeshmepco@gmail.com

Comment: Did you receive the email?